# D3Plus Scatter Plot X axix String

Tags: javascript, string, d3.js, d3plus

I like to know if it's possible to pass a "string" to the X axis of a D3Plus Scatter Plot like this:

```
 // sample data array
  var sample_data = [
    {"value": 100, "weight": .45, "type": "alpha"},
    {"value": 70, "weight": .60, "type": "beta"},
    {"value": 40, "weight": -.2, "type": "gamma"},
    {"value": 15, "weight": .1, "type": "delta"}
  ]
  // instantiate d3plus
  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")  // container DIV to hold the visualization
    .data(sample_data)  // data to use with the visualization
    .type("scatter")    // visualization type
    .id("type")         // key for which our data is unique on
    .x("type")         // key for x-axis
    .y("weight")        // key for y-axis
    .draw()             // finally, draw the visualization!
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8opdr9t5/1/)

with this configuration I have this error 
***Uncaught TypeError: testScale.invert is not a function***

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
  // instantiate d3plus
  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")  // container DIV to hold the visualization
    .data(sample_data)  // data to use with the visualization
    .type("scatter")    // visualization type
    .id("type")         // key for which our data is unique on
    .x("value")         // key for x-axis
    .y("weight")        // key for y-axis
    .draw()             // finally, draw the visualization!
```